# Why Synchronize is being locked by ShowModal?

Tags: delphi

I created a generic thread class that controls a progress form which is injected in the constructor of the thread and set as `_progressForm`. At the Execute method, the thread initializes the form and shows it using the function ShowModal() as shown below:

```
procedure TProgressThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  ShowForm;
end;

procedure TProgressThread.ShowForm;
begin
  if Assigned(_progressForm) then
  begin
    Synchronize(
      procedure
      begin
        _progressForm.ShowModal();
      end);
  end;
end;
```

What I can't understand is why my thread is locked at Synchronize? It doesn't return until the progress form is closed. Shouldn't ShowModal only lock the main thread?

Comment: If you use Synchronize, the calling thread is blocked until it returns. ShowModal runs in the context of the main thread, so it will block until the form closes.

Comment: Seems like you're taking the wrong approach to a common problem. The appropriate solution would be to do your *work* inside of a thread, not displaying your *progress*.

Comment: This is a little bug winded way to call ShowModal from the main thread. Think about it.

Comment: Thank you guys. @JerryDodge,  what you be a better generic approach to do this? Make the form call the thread from OnFormShow event?

Comment: @noen: No. Have the thread asynchronously post progress updates to the main thread, and let the main thread decide how to display the status while the thread continues with its work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TThread.Synchronize()` is **synchronous**. It blocks the calling thread until the synced code returns from the main thread.

`ShowModal()` is also **synchronous**. It blocks the calling thread until the Form is closed.

So, when `Synchronize()` calls `ShowModal()` in the main thread, `Synchronize()` will not return to the worker thread until the Form is closed.

If you don't want to block the worker thread, either use `TThread.Queue()` instead of `TThread.Synchronize()`, or use `TForm.Show()` instead of `TForm.ShowModal()`.

Display of progress should not block the worker thread from doing its work.  You should have the thread **asynchronously** post progress updates to the main thread, and let the main thread decide how to display the status while the thread continues with its work.  The worker thread should have no knowledge of the UI at all.

Comment: Remy how about using PostMessage to post the progress to the main thread

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout: that is perfectly fine, as long as you use an `HWND` that is safe for that usage. DO NOT use an `HWND` from the `TWinControl::Handle` property! It is not persistent nor thread-safe. Use `TApplication::Handle`, or an `HWND` you create yourself with  `AllocateHWND()` or `CreateWindow/Ex()`